# mongodb aggregate not match query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nodes

I have a collection name users details below

```
[{
"userId": "00UPQAARGT7",
"userPreferences": [{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48CB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "CSV"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "E"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "DOC"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
}
]},
{
"userId": "02UPQAARST7",
"userPreferences": [
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "CSV"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB",
    "pData": [{
            "name": "FORMAT",
            "value": "PPT"
        },
        {
            "name": "LAN",
            "value": "N"
        }
    ]
}
]}
```

]
and have another collection products

```
[{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48CB",
    "rInfo": {
        "format": "TAB"
    },
    "LAN": "P",
    "cPro": "TRUE"
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48CB",
    "rInfo": {
        "format": "SHAPE"
    },
    "LAN": "N",
    "cPro": "FALSE"
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48DB",
    "rInfo": {
        "format": "CSV"
    },
    "LAN": "E",
    "cPro": "TRUE"
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D48DB",
    "rInfo": {
        "format": "CSV"
    },
    "LAN": "E",
    "cPro": "TRUE"
},
{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB",
    "rInfo": {
        "format": "SQL"
    },
    "LAN": "E",
    "cPro": "TRUE"
}

]
```

Now I want to fetch all users with matching pId from products collection using mongodb query where userId.userPreferences.pData name/value combination doesn't match with products.rInfo.format and products.LAN basically output will be below, any help

```
[{
"userId": "00UPQAARGT7",
"userPreferences": [{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB"
}]
},
{
"userId": "02UPQAARST7",
 "userPreferences": [{
    "pId": "59SDS64675A00096D59DB"
}]
}]
```

Comment: Can you change your pData field in first collection to  `"pData":{"FORMAT":"CSV",  "LAN": "N"  }` ?  This will help you with checking equality condition.

Comment: @Veeram i can't change.

Comment: Okay what is your mongo server version ?

Comment: @Veeram Version 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation stages, I will explain the 4 stages in the query.

1. $unwind will literally unwind your array of products so mongo can work individually for each object you have.
2. $lookup will do a join users-products.
3. $project (optional) will write a custom output of the data you need; I write it based on your request.
4. $groupby group the result using the userId as key.

Query:

```
db.name.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$userPreferences"
    },
    {
        $lookup:
            {
                from: "products",
                localField: "userPreferences.pId",
                foreignField: "pId",
                as: "product"
            }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            userId: 1,
            "userPref": "$product.pId",
        }
    },
    {
        $group : { _id : "$userId" }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Right now I don't have a terminal to test the query, but I'm pretty sure will work. Please comment any error so I can modify my answer.

Comment: If you have curious about aggregation please read docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline